# Get an error when using Livy to submit Spark jobs: User did not initialize spark context

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I am very new to Spark and I am following this document to submit Spark jobs via Livy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-livy-rest-interface

Here's my command:

```
curl -k --user "username:password!" -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "file":"/test4spark/test4sparkhaha.jar", "className":"helloworld4spark.test" }' "https://xxx.azurehdinsight.net/livy/batches" -H "X-Requested-By: username"
```

The file test4sparkhaha.jar is a super simple Java application, it contains only one class, and there's only a main method that print "hahaha", nothing else...
I exported the project in Eclipse to a Runnable Jar and I tried run it on my spark cluster using **Java -jar** and **Spark-submit**. Both worked good. 
Then I started to try submit the job via Livy and it always failed, I found below errors in Yarn logs:

19/11/06 14:36:06 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context!
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:510)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:345)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$5.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:815)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:259)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:839)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)

Here's the **Spark-submit** command I tried:

```
spark-submit --class helloworld4spark.test test4sparkhaha.jar
```

It works perfectly...

Can you guys please help me to understand why it gives the error while **Spark-submit** works fine?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to submit local `.jar` file with Livy.
For spark-submit it works (submitting job to Yarn supports it), but for Livy server it doesn't.

To make it work you need to upload your jar to the hdfs/wasbs/adls/http accessible location (be sure that your Spark is configured to access that location).

Please refer the first paragraph of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-livy-rest-interface#submit-an-apache-livy-spark-batch-job) guide.

Comment: Hi Aliaksandr, thank you for replying!. I did try WASB path at first, but it throws an error saying "ClassNotFound". It is wierd because the error makes no sense so I guess the reason it gives such error is that the WASB path can't return the jar file properly. So I uploaded the jar file from local to HDFS, "/test4spark/test4sparkhaha.jar" is HDFS path

Comment: Hi Chase, be sure to use path in a format `wasb://<mycontainer>@<mystorageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/test4sparkhaha.jar`. As well be sure that your cluster is configured to access that blob container. Usually when you're running HDInsight you mount Blob Storage account to the cluster, which can be accessible without providing additional credentials, so use it. And your class name looks unusual, feels like you point to the package name, it should be like `helloworld4spark.test.MyClassWithMain`.